# pattern match from a string with regex

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to match 2 sets of pattern from text input. From the below example, can I extract numbers which has any of the following character set mg/mcg/ml/g

> Meropenem Hospira  Powder for Injection (10 Vial of 20 ml)  500mg should match 20 ml and 500mg.

My regex `([\d+\.+\d+]+(mg|g|mcg|ml|)+)+` matches 10 , 20 ml , 500mg

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: output should be only the digits that are followed by mg/mcg/ml/g like 20 ml and 500mg

Comment: Do you really want potentially multiple decimal points?

Comment: Try something like `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: ?(?:m|m[gl]|mgc))?`

Comment: What about [`\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*(?:m?g|mcg|ml)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/nnUFjH/2)?

Comment: yes, since I match them against another column to find the common rows.

Comment: @CAustin OP doesn't want to match `10`

Comment: @ctwheels My bad, misunderstood that part. @MC12 I'm not sure I understand that requirement. Can you give an example of some potential input that contains multiple `.`s?

Comment: @ctwheels how do I get the characters following the digits with your regex?

Comment: You can use either `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*(m?g|mcg|ml)\b)` or `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(m?g|mcg|ml)\b`

Comment: @CAustin `MARCAINE SPINAL 0.75% INJ  in 0.5 ml solution`

Comment: That shouldn't require a pattern with multiple `.`s because each match will only contain one. The patterns that ctwheels posted should be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

`([\d*.?\d+]+\s*(?:mg|g|mcg|ml)(?![a-z,A-Z])+)`

This worked for me. The two problems I noticed with your expression was wrapping the units in `()` instead of `[]` and not specifically calling out whitespace characters as a possibility.

This also assumes that the regex you're using can handle non-capture groups `(?:)`

This will not match 20 g in something like "20 graphites", for example.

Comment: The above regex has the output (3 c
`Nivestim (3 concetrations)`
For this example it should not match at all

Comment: Edited my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you `(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*(g|m(?:c?g|l))`

https://regex101.com/r/bKMmKi/1

Per Match:
Quantity in group 1
Volume units in group 2

Formatted:

```
 (                             # (1 start), The decimal amount
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s*                           # Optional whitespace
 (                             # (2 start), The allowed volume units
      g
   |  m
      (?: c?g | l )
 )                             # (2 end)
```